# Jenkins pipeline CopyArtifact for GHOF

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Im trying to copy an artifact from my github organization folder setup(from a specific branch build) and I'm not able to specify the correct project name from which I should copy nor I can configure the folder jobs with: "Permission to Copy Artifact" as the GHOF configurations doesn't have such an option.

I've tried the following path with no success:

```
step([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
                 fingerprintArtifacts: true,
                  projectName: 'project/job/repo/job/branch'])
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Try the path as an absolute path `/project/..`.

Comment: Didnt work. when im trying to copy from regular job im just providing:   projectName: 'job name' and its working.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
copyArtifacts filter: 'version.properties', projectName: 'org/testlib/master'
```

I didn't need to escape the '/' as suggested in another question. 'org' is my github org name, 'testlib' is the repo, and 'master' is the branch.